# Readlines() vs. Read() - Can I convert data back and forth between the two functions?

Tags: python

I have a module file containing the following functions:

```
def replace(filename):
    match = re.sub(r'[^\s^\w]risk', 'risk', filename)
    return match

def count_words(newstring):
    from collections import defaultdict
    word_dict=defaultdict(int)
    for line in newstring:
        words=line.lower().split()
        for word in words:
            word_dict[word]+=1

    for word in word_dict:
        if'risk'==word:
           return word, word_dict[word]
```

when I do this in IDLE:

```
>>> mylist = open('C:\\Users\\ahn_133\\Desktop\\Python Project\\test10.txt').read()
>>> newstrings=replace(mylist)    
>>> newone=count_words(newstrings)
```

test10.txt just contains words for testing like:

#

risk risky riskier risk. risk?

#

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#134>", line 1, in <module>
    newPH = replace(newPassage)
  File "C:\Users\ahn_133\Desktop\Python Project\text_modules.py", line 56, in replace
    match = re.sub(r'[^\s^\w]risk', 'risk', filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Is there anyway to run both functions without saving `newstrings` into a file, opening it using `readlines()`, and then running `count_words` function?

Comment: The traceback says the error happens when you write `newPH = replace(newPassage)`. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: Aside: I think you might want to change your variable names.  `mylist` isn't a list, `filename` isn't a filename, `match` isn't a match object, `newstrings` isn't a collection of strings, and `newone` is a 2-tuple.  By itself, any one of those wouldn't be so bad, but the set of them is a little confusing.

Comment: Yea I think the problem here is that you arent quite sure what types any of your own variables are

Comment: You should post also an example of the input file.

Comment: Also you say the replace function works fine yet your traceback shows the replace failing.

Comment: -1 What is the problem you are trying to solve? Your questions' title has nothing to do with the actual question, you don't tell what you are trying to so basically you just expect people to just debug your broken code _without_ posting the full code. Please heavily revise your question.

Answer (score 0):

To run a module, you just do `python modulename.py` or `python.exe modulename.py` - or just double click the icon.

But i guess your problem really isn't what your question title states, so you really should learn [how to debug python](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+debugging+tutorial)